# Use functions form other classes in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I would like to create a class that will contain a few functions to be used in all the code.

I'm doing this:

MAIN CLASS

```
class ListaAbitudini extends StatefulWidget {

  final Function scegliIcona;
  ListaAbitudini({this.scegliIcona});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _ListaAbitudiniState();
  }
}

class _ListaAbitudiniState extends State<ListaAbitudini> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   widget.scegliIcona();
   ... 
  }
}
```

CLASS WITH THE FUNCTION

```
class FindIcone {

  Icon scegliIcona(){ ... }

  ListaAbitudini(scegliIcona);

}
```

The problem is that I have an error on this line: `'ListaAbitudini(scegliIcona);'` saying that `"ListaAbitudini must have a method body because FindIcone isn't abstract".`

What am I doing wrong? HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you use is for parent widget to child widget. In your case you can Create new object of `FindIcone` and call the method.

```
class ListaAbitudini extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _ListaAbitudiniState();
  }
}

class _ListaAbitudiniState extends State<ListaAbitudini> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FindIcone().scegliIcona();
  }
}

class FindIcone {
  Icon scegliIcona() {
    return Icon(Icons.ac_unit);
  }
```

Also you can use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).